# Problem with using aircrack-ng

Tags: linux, wep

I have problem with install a Aircrack-ng.
I was downloading aircrack from the official website and I followed to the ruls:

```
cd aircrack-ng-1.1
make
make install
```

http://pastebin.com/XsMzCbGN

Answer (score 2):

Look at line 21:  `crypto.h:12:26: fatal error: openssl/hmac.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type`

It appears you don't have openssl properly installed?  You also should run "make install" as sudo (if you don't have admin rights)

Alternatively, if you're using Ubuntu (or similar distro), aircrack-ng should be in your repositories, so you don't need to install it from source:

`sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`

Comment: I trying follow hard to the ruls and I need to run the commmand:

    sudo apt-get install build-essential

 i did runnned the command and i got a message:

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: that adds the building capabilities to run the make:
dpkg-dev,
g++,
gcc,
libc6-dev,
 and make.

You still need to install the other requirements.  In this case, openssl:
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev openssl